# security of a php page

Tags: php, security

If I need to design an interface in php that has to be online and needs a database beside and I am the only one that has to use it. What kind of protection should I implemet more than:
- limited the ip address access to the php page
- using a login/password with relatives controls
- using a session variable

The purpose is to design my own accounting program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DB and Web Server are the same box:

1. Firewall everything so that only Port 80 and Port 443 are open to
   the public. This way only your PHP Scripts can interact with the DB.
2. Redirect any HTTP traffic to HTTPS to ensure secure connection
   between Client Browser and Web Server.
3. Store sensitive data in the
   DB with encryption. This will help ensure that if someone does
   perform injection, they cannot see plain text info.

If they are on separate servers, do the same things, just make sure there is a secure connection between the two.

Comment: Thats a good point. I only mention to secure the php page but I forgot about the DB.

Comment: Glad it could help. Feel free to mark it as an answer if it addresses your original question. And good luck.

Comment: Can you cite an example where one would use encryption in the database? This is possibly rarer than you think - translucent databases come to mind - but in general if your database has been leaked, then your decryption key may have leaked too.

Comment: From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html, `INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,AES_ENCRYPT('text', SHA2('My secret passphrase',512)));`

Comment: (It's worth using handles e.g. @halfer - I didn't get a notification from you here).

Comment: Your example would usually not be best practice - in fact this is why I asked. Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted. That said, I can imagine there are some edge cases, such as remote service passwords, where there is no-one to type them in. I wanted to comment so as to avoid readers thinking that encryption by itself is a magic solution - of course a decryption key has to be available to the app too, and is also liable to be stolen by a knowledgeable attacker.

Comment: I would not use this to store a Password. Only sensitive user data, for example a Street Address. I agree completely that passwords should be hashed. I was simply suggesting that sensitive user data that might be contained in an accounting DB should be encrypted such that if someone is able to peer into the DB for whatever reason, the data they would get back is not easily used. If someone was scraping for emails... the data inside the DB would be less viable to a malicious user as they would not know the secret passphrase.